# How to separate jQuery validation methods into a file/class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, idioms

How to separate jQuery validation methods in a seperate file/class.

```
$.validator.addMethod("specialChrs",function(element, value) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\d= ]+$/.test(value)
}, "Special Characters not permitted");
```

I have this kind of valdidation in many files for different forms.
How can i keep them `separate` and `generic` in one `class`. Can anyone recommend me some design patterns used while separating jQuery functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JQuery in a separate .js file and link to it in your html files in the head section with the script tags.

Separate .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("specialChrs",function(element, value) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\d= ]+$/.test(value)
    }, "Special Characters not permitted");
});
```

In your htlm file

```
<head>
    <script src="../yourjquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Also have a look at [this](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.nl/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html) link.